# Is there a Npgsql release that works with TLS 1.2 and Azure Data Catalog?

Tags: azure, tls1.2, npgsql, azure-data-catalog, azure-database-postgresql

could you please advise how I can use Npgsql to enable Azure Data Catalog (ADC) to access an Azure Database for PostgreSQL Server using TLS >= 1.2?

I get the following error when I use the local application for ADC:

- When I have no Npgsql version installed
- When I have Npgsql version 4.1.4 installed

[image: Error with ADC and Npgsql]

I get the following error when I use the local application for ADC, and have Npgsql version 2.2.4.3 installed, and the Postgres server uses minimum TLS >= 1.1:
[image: Error 2 with ADC and Npgsql]

I am able to use the local application for ADC to connect to Postgres, when I set the minimum TLS version to 1.0. However my workplace requires TLS 1.2.
I am receiving a similar issue in Power BI, so I assume this issue is not specific to ADC.
[image]

Things I've tried:

- [Searching the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure%20data%20catalog%20postgres%20tls&rlz=1C1GCEB_enAU874AU874&oq=azure%20data%20catalog%20postgres%20tls&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.7072j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I found no applicable info.
- [Raising the issue with Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/70449/cannot-connect-azure-data-catalog-to-azure-databas.html). They have not provided an answer.

Comment: There are known issues with the npgsql data provider 4.1.x itself, please check this GitHub issue https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677#issuecomment-541219594  The workaround is to use version 4.0.9 This is suggested on the issue you raised on Microsoft Q&A as well. Please scroll to the bottom of the page and click "show more comments" in case the comments are collapsed.

Comment: Hi Kalyan, thank you for that link. You are correct, I did not notice Microsoft's additional comments.
I am now getting a slightly different issue with Azure Data Catalog that might still be related to Npgsql, I updated the Microsoft Q&A with that issue.
Do you recommend I update this Stack Overflow question? Or close it and instead comment on the GitHub issue you linked?

Comment: The issue with npgsql is not something Microsoft can help with. You may want to follow the Github issue to get notified with it is fixed so that you can upgrade to the latest version. But you can update the question on here on Stack so that other users can suggest workarounds if any. We will continue to assist you on Microsoft Q&A